# how to give a page curl animation on a click event of ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating one Book application ,where i want a page curl effect on a button click.

**i already refer the"harism project of page curl"** ,
it is very good reference ,but effect is given on a touch event.

but i dont know how to apply 
same effect on button click.

means when i click forward or next button ,next page should appear with page curl effect.

or there is some another solution for this,

Any reference ,Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks in advance